# Why isn't my multiple orderby working?

Tags: wp-query, menu-order

I have a custom category page with the following query:

```
$args = array(  
   'cat'  => $portfolioCategories,   
   'posts_per_page'     => $itemsPerPage,  
   'orderby'            => 'menu_order date',   
   'order'              => 'DESC',   
   'paged'              => $paged   
);   
query_posts( $args );
```

So `'orderby' => 'menu_order'` works just fine. `'orderby' => 'date'` works just fine.

But `'orderby' => 'menu_order date'` does not work - I get some weird completely random order.

What have I done wrong?

PS: Yes, I have enabled page attributes (ie, menu order) for posts in my functions file
PPS: I get the same results whether I use `query_posts($args)` or `new WP_Query($args)`

EDIT: The SQL generated looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_rk2ukj_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_rk2ukj_posts 
 INNER JOIN wp_rk2ukj_term_relationships ON (wp_rk2ukj_posts.ID = wp_rk2ukj_term_relationships.object_id) 
 WHERE 1=1  
   AND ( wp_rk2ukj_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (89,93,94,95,96,106) ) 
   AND wp_rk2ukj_posts.post_type = 'post' 
   AND (wp_rk2ukj_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_rk2ukj_posts.post_status = 'private') 
 GROUP BY wp_rk2ukj_posts.ID
 ORDER BY wp_rk2ukj_posts.menu_order,wp_rk2ukj_posts.post_date DESC
 LIMIT 0, 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

You can use multiple fields in `orderby` argument. Codex [shows you](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) how to do it (and you do it correctly):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order date', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

And it should solve your problem. (It should, but if you want to sort DESC it probably won't, because of this WordPress bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

Of course you always can use [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter to create your own `ORDER BY` part of query.

```
function my_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = "YOUR ORDER BY STATEMENT";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby');
```

Just add this filter just before you call your query and remove it after.

Comment: Even if I use `new WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`, it still doesn't work. I do want both parameters ordered DESC (so independent sorting is not an issue). I'm wondering if it isn't the `GROUPBY` clause being returned in the SQL?

Comment: Read carefully pls. It's a bug in WordPress code. Multiple orderby won't work, if you use `DESC` order. The only way to do it now is to use `posts_orderby` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above comment from Krzysiek Dróżdż I use in my code:

```
 add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_product_order_by_sort');
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => $category->slug);
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
   .....
 remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_product_order_by_sort');
```

So I added function with multiple order:

```
function my_product_order_by_sort($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = "wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.id ASC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```